# What is the piece of furniture in the new Beauty and the Beast?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In the film there is a piece of furniture that is white and is shaped kinda wiggly. It appears in Belle's room and behind the singer at the end of the movie.

[image]

What is it?

Comment: An image here would be helpful.

Comment: Is it a living object?

Comment: http://68.media.tumblr.com/0bd79c18641a1006c1e5f580052278a4/tumblr_inline_ondqs4jZNL1qg4h6q_1280.jpg

Comment: In the picture above the  piece of furniture is in the back right behind madam garderobe

Comment: http://cdn.inquisitr.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/belles-bedroom-670x388.jpg

Comment: Here it is in the bedroom to the right

Answer (score 3):

The object mentioned and seen in this picture [image: Oven] is a baroque ceramic oven used for heating.

See more pictures of similar objects e.g. here: ["Antique" ovens on Pinterest](https://de.pinterest.com/gbsnetworks/antique-ceramic-stoves/).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/670o82/what_is_this_strange_piece_of_furniture_in_belles/

It's evidently a baroque room over or heater. To keep the room warm.[image]

Answer (score -1):

That's Madame Garderobe, the furniture that the singer was transformed into by the curse.  Google that word for various definitions, but functionally it is a dresser or wardrobe.

Comment: No not the wardrobe, there is another piece of furniture in the room that is white and it is behind madame garderobe at the end of the movie

Comment: It's doesn't seem to be living at all but in belles room it has its own  recessed in the wall